# Migrating multistage Dockerfile to bazel

Tags: docker, bazel, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM oracle/graalvm-ce:19.3.1-java11 as graalvm
RUN gu install native-image
COPY . /home/app/monolith
WORKDIR /home/app/monolith
RUN ./gradlew clean build
RUN native-image --no-server -cp build/libs/monolith-*-all.jar

FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
RUN apk update && apk add libstdc++
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=graalvm /home/app/monolith/monolith /app/monolith
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/monolith"]
```

It is quite simple. In the first stage it creates a native-image from the jar and in the second it uses a tiny alpine image to run that binary. I want to migrate it to bazel.

I pull both bases in my workspace like this:

```
container_pull (
      name = "graalvm",
      registry = "index.docker.io",
      repository = "oracle/graalvm-ce",
      tag = "20.0.0-java11",
)
container_pull (
      name = "alpine_glibc",
      registry = "index.docker.io",
      repository = "frolvlad/alpine-glibc",
      tag = "glibc-2.30",
)
```

After this I am not sure to use the first image with a `java_library` and *inject* the result into the second to generate the resulting image.

Comment: Do you want to use jar created from first image to second docker image?

Comment: The first image is fed the jar and outputs a binary, the second is what I would want to push since it contains a tiny image and the binary. The first image only exists because it _knows_ how to create the binary.